# Invalid block tag. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, html, django

Getting an invalid block tag message `Invalid block tag on line 2: 'out'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?` but don't know why. Here's my setup:

graphs.html

```
{% out %}
```

views.py

```
out = 'something to say'
template = loader.get_template('viz_proj/graphs.html')
context = {
    'out' : out
} 
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'viz_proj'
]
```

project heirarchy

```
viz_proj
|
viz_proj----------------------------------------templates
    |                                              |
    settings.py--views.py--urls.py               graphs.html
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you want to try {{ out }} instead of {% out %}.

Comment: No worries, if I had a dollar for every time I did that I would have like 20 bucks by now.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is `{{out}}` and not `{% out %}`. This is because `out` is a variable.

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#the-django-template-language